# Android: How do I dynamically show/hide an element in a ListView item depending on the Array value?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, listitem

im trying to create a ListView filled with items fetched from an API, and depending on a variable, I want to show/hide an TextView in my ListView item layout for that row.

My ListView item layout contains 3 TextViews. One is hidden on default using android:visibilty:"GONE".

I am using a this for my ListAdapter:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Attach to:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                            new String[] { "title", "info","comments", "score" }, 
                            new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.post_comments, R.id.post_score });
setListAdapter(adapter);
final ListView lv = getListView();
```

**So my question is, how can I iterate the whole list to check if "VariableA" == "something" then show the hidden TextView within that single item?**

Or is there a way to dynamically Insert a TextView in that a single ListView item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create Custom Adapter For Listview and write Some Logic in

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if("variable1".equals("something")){
         //create view here For row

     }    else{
         //create another view here For row
   }

  return row;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to implement `getView()` at all, using a custom view binder check your flag and set that view invisible or gone. Since you're already using a view binder its easier to implement than `getView()`